# How to obtain entire path with request parameters in Reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, react-router

In Reactjs when we use React Router as manager to our page browsing we receive location object as one of the props:

```
<Route path="/search" render={(props) => ( <SearchPage {...props} /> )} exact />
```

Then from inside of the component (here SearchPage as an example) the path can be obtained in following way:

```
var currentPathname = this.props.location.pathname;
console.log("Current pathname is: " + currentPathname);
```

OUTPUT:

```
Current pathname is: /search
```

But is we have a pattern where searchText request parameter is present for example:

```
 /search?searchText=NissanSilvia
```

Then still this.props.location.pathname will yield only:

```
 /search
```

How can I get full path with all present request parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use location.pathname and location.search please:

```
this.props.location.pathname+this.props.location.search
```

Answer (score 2):

`location.search` returns the query string

So you can do:

```
const {pathanme, search} = this.props.location
console.log(pathname + search)
```

Answer (score 1):

The following values are available at location object [`Location API Ref`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/location)

```
{
  key: 'ac3df4', // not with HashHistory!
  pathname: '/somewhere'
  search: '?some=search-string',
  hash: '#howdy',
  state: {
    [userDefined]: true
  }
}
```

For URL you're looking for you can take `pathname` and `search` key i.e.

```
let { search, pathname } = this.location
console.log( pathname + search )
```